# HTML tags not being processed in a velocity file

Tags: spring, tomcat, velocity

I have a spring app which uses velocity. There is a quartz scheduler that runs every few minutes and sends out emails. The email's content is generated from a velocity template. The problem is that if that app is run using the maven's tomcat plugin, then the HTML tags in the email template file are processed correctly. But if I put that app in a standalone tomcat installation and run it from there, the tags show up in the email as

```
<p> <br />
```

, and no dynamic content is set. I can't figure out what the exact problem is. Is some jar in my app conflicting with the tomcat instance? Here's a list of the jars in its lib folder :

```
activation-1.1.jar                             juli-6.0.32.jar
activemq-all-5.4.2.jar                         junit-4.8.1.jar
annogen-0.1.0.jar                              log4j-1.2.16.jar
ant-1.7.0.jar                                  lucene-analyzers-3.1.0.jar
ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar                         lucene-core-3.1.0.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar                                lucene-highlighter-3.1.0.jar
ant-nodeps-1.7.0.jar                           lucene-memory-3.1.0.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar                            lucene-misc-3.1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar                                    lucene-smartcn-3.1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar                            lucene-spatial-3.1.0.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar                        lucene-spellchecker-3.1.0.jar
axiom-api-1.2.7.jar                            lucene-stempel-3.1.0.jar
axiom-dom-1.2.5.jar                            mail-1.4.jar
axiom-impl-1.2.7.jar                           mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar
axis2-1.4.jar                                  neethi-3.0.0.jar
axis2-adb-1.3.jar                              opencsv-2.1.jar
axis2-adb-codegen-1.3.jar                      opensaml-1.1.jar
axis2-codegen-1.3.jar                          oro-2.0.8.jar
axis2-kernel-1.3.jar                           quartz-1.6.1.jar
axis2-mtompolicy-1.3.jar                       rampart-core-1.3.jar
axis2-xmlbeans-1.3.jar                         rampart-policy-1.3.jar
axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar                          rampart-trust-1.3.jar
backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar               slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
cas-client-core-3.1.10.jar                     slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar
cglib-2.2.jar                                  solr-analysis-extras-3.1.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar                    solr-commons-csv-3.1.0.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar                          solr-core-3.1.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar                  solr-solrj-3.1.0.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar                         spring-aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
commons-digester-1.7.jar                       spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar                      spring-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar                   spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar                     spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-io-2.0.jar                             spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar                           spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar                      spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-pool-1.3.jar                           spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-validator-1.3.0.jar                    spring-jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                                spring-modules-validation-0.8.jar
ehcache-core-2.2.0.jar                         spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar         spring-oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar             spring-security-cas-client-    3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.jar                  spring-security-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.1.1.jar             spring-security-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar           spring-tx-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.5.4-Final.jar          spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar  spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
hibernate-core-3.5.4-Final.jar                 spring-ws-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.4-Final.jar        spring-xml-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar          stax2-api-3.0.2.jar
hibernate-search-3.4.1.Final.jar               stax-api-1.0.1.jar
hibernate-search-analyzers-3.4.1.Final.jar     stax-api-1.0-2.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar            
httpcore-4.0-alpha5.jar                        
httpcore-nio-4.0-alpha5.jar                    tribes-6.0.32.jar
httpcore-niossl-4.0-alpha5.jar                 validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
icu4j-2.6.1.jar                                velocity-1.6.4.jar
itextpdf-5.1.1.jar                             velocity-tools-1.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.5.3.jar                     woden-api-1.0M9.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.3.jar                   woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar
jasypt-1.8.jar                                 wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar                         ws-humanresources-13.0.1.jar
jaxen-1.1.jar                                  wss4j-1.5.3.jar
jdom-1.0.jar                                   wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar
jetty-continuation-8.0.0.M3.jar                xalan-2.7.0.jar
jetty-http-8.0.0.M3.jar                        xbean-2.1.0.jar
jetty-io-8.0.0.M3.jar                          xbean-spring-3.6.jar
jetty-server-8.0.0.M3.jar                      xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
jetty-util-8.0.0.M3.jar                        xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
joda-time-1.6.jar                              xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
js-1.6R2.jar                                   XmlSchema-1.3.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar                                   xmlsec-1.4.0.jar
jta-1.1.jar                                    xom-1.0.jar
```

The content of the velocity template is :

```
#if( ${user.middleName} )
#set( $fullName = "${user.firstName} ${user.middleName} ${user.lastName}" )
#else
#set( $fullName = "${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}" )
#end
#set( $subject = "User name for ${fullName} is changed" ) 
#set( $from = "test@test.com" )
#set( $to = "${user.email}" )

<p>Hi ${fullName}</p>

<p>Thanks!<br></p>
```

Any help is appreciated because I am at my wit's end.

Comment: There is no "processing" of the HTML tags, they're simply emitted-it's more likely to be a mimetype/etc issue.

Comment: But what about the variables like ${fullName} which aren't processed either. I forgot to mention one thing though, that this file is in a dependency.

Comment: Without knowing anything about how/where you're setting the context up it's impossible to know for sure. It's possible it's a library conflict, but hard to say.

Comment: My guess is that there is something off in your Spring wiring. Also, check your logs and see if there are any warnings\exceptions. Aside from that, you'd have to show much more, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the characters are being escaped... best to look at the html source but it's likely you'll see < and > instead of < and >. This would typically happen (depending on config) if you passed html into a velocity template in the velocity context. This shouldn't be the case for you though, as your html code is already in the template but it is being escaped somewhere.

I think the escaping is happening after velocity has processed the template. You should take a look at your tomcat config and also what you're doing with the email after processing the template

Sorry I can't be of more help but there isn't a lot to go on in your question

Answer (score 0):

Is the email is being sent as text/plain instead of text/html. Check out the mime type and see if it's correct